using GCG with multithreads solvers
I am looking for a sensible alternative to commercial LP solvers like CPLEX and GUROBI.
I successfuly used GCG and FiberSCIP separately. My question is : is it possible to use the benefits of them two : (i) the decomposition from GCG and (ii) the multithread capability of FiberSCIP.
Thanks for your help
Maxime
Looked into the GCG documentation to check if FiberSCIP or other solvers could be called instead of SCIP (single thread).
